# How do I return a random specified amount in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a game where the user gets to chose the number of dice in their hand. My code wont output any of the dice (until I use it later in my main). When they do show up later in my main the first number is random, but the rest are zero and there are always five dice (even if I input that I only want two or three). Does anyone know why my user input isnt giving me the correct output??

Here is what I am getting for the output:

[image: output]

Here is my main:

```java
public class yahtzee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int play = 1, scorea = 0, sum = 0;
        int[] wins = new int[15];

        while ((play == 1) && (sum < 15)) {
            sum = 0;

            int[] Dice = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};// creates an array
            int roll = 0;
            int x, y, w, z;
            int rerolla = 0, rerollb = 03;
            dice die = new dice();
            yahtzeeConfig config = new yahtzeeConfig();

            for (x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
                Dice[x] = config.Sides();
                die.roll();
                //Dice[x] = die.get();// sets the dice values
                //Dice[x]= config.Sides();
            }
            System.out.println("\nHere is your roll:\n");

            if (Dice[x] == 1) {
                System.out.println("Die 1: " + Dice[0]);
            }
            if (Dice[x] == 2) {
                System.out.println("Die 1: " + Dice[0]);
                System.out.println("Die 2: " + Dice[1]);
            }
            if (Dice[x] == 3) {
                System.out.println("Die 1: " + Dice[0]);
                System.out.println("Die 2: " + Dice[1]);
                System.out.println("Die 3: " + Dice[2]);
            }
            if (Dice[x] == 4) {
                System.out.println("Die 1: " + Dice[0]);
                System.out.println("Die 2: " + Dice[1]);
                System.out.println("Die 3: " + Dice[2]);
                System.out.println("Die 4: " + Dice[3]);
            }
            if (Dice[x] == 5) {
                //System.out.println("\nHere is your roll:\n");
                System.out.println("Die 1: " + Dice[0]);
                System.out.println("Die 2: " + Dice[1]);
                System.out.println("Die 3: " + Dice[2]);
                System.out.println("Die 4: " + Dice[3]);
                System.out.println("Die 5: " + Dice[4]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my yahtzeeConfig class:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class yahtzeeConfig {
    public int Sides() {
        String file = "yahtzeeConfig.txt";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //configures sides of dice
        System.out.println("Enter the number of " +
                "sides you would like on each dice (1-6): ");
        int sides = scan.nextInt();
        return sides;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you step through your code with the debugger I think you'll find the problem pretty quickly. Without seeing what the `dice` class is it isn't possible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return 6 random numbers from the method `Slides()` you could use

```java
final int[] dicesRandom = new Random().ints(1, 6).distinct().toArray();
```

Implementing in your method

```java
public int[] Sides() {
    String file = "yahtzeeConfig.txt";

    final int[] dicesRandom = new Random().ints(1, 6).distinct().toArray();

    return dicesRandom;
}
```

And in the main class you don't need to get through the for loop, just call this method and it will generate 6 numbers for you.